# Updating airflow variable which contains a dictionary

Tags: airflow

We have a certain scenario where we need to update an airflow variable which looks like
'status': {'t1':'op1', 't2':'op2'}

Multiple tasks in the dag need to update this variable and add their own entry into this dictionary. When tasks are in sequence, the updation works fine using Variable.set() ,however, when tasks are in parallel, the updates are getting lost. For example if task9 and task10 are in parallel, only the entry 't10' was added while 't9' was lost and not added to the variable

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have race condition between tasks that cause the tasks to overwrite each other.

It might be better to create a task at the end of all parallel tasks that update this variable with the return_value from other tasks .